# How to use command line aliases to create a junction using paths with spaces in Cmder

Tags: windows, command-line, alias, junction, cmder

I am using Cmder on Windows 10 (ConEmu 161206 [64] stable). I want to create an alias called **cloud** that creates a junction. Here's what I have typed in Cmder:

```
alias cloud=mklink /J "C:\Users\chjensen\OneDrive - chjensen\$1" "$2"
```

Let's say I want to create a link folder called Sublime, and the target is my Sublime packages at **C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages**. I try this:

```
cloud sublime C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages
```

But that command results in the following output:

**Junction created for C:\Users\chjensen\OneDrive - chjensen\sublime <<===>> C:\Program**

The 1st path is correct, but the 2nd path - **C:\Program** - is being cut off at the first space. When I try to access the link directory I can't, obviously, because it's trying to link to C:\Program, which doesn't exist.

If I write the entire command manually it works:

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\chjensen\OneDrive - chjensen\sublime" "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages"
```

**Junction created for C:\Users\chjensen\OneDrive - chjensen\sublime <<===>> C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages**

I have also tried using the quotes in the actual command:

```
alias cloud=mklink /J "C:\Users\chjensen\OneDrive - chjensen\$1" $2
cloud sublime "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages"
```

but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue you can use the following code (this is not a very elegant solution, but it will work reasonably well). Note that I'm using `c:\temp` to test rather than your home directory, but its the same concept:

```powershell
alias cloud=mklink /J "C:\temp\OneDrive - chjensen\$1" $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

This would be the MS cmd command:

```powershell
cloud sublime "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages"
```

Here's an easy way to debug the alias, but using an `echo` command to put it to the terminal:

```powershell
alias cloudp=echo mklink /J "C:\temp\OneDrive - chjensen\$1" $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

As you've already mentioned, the issue that you're running into is that `$2` is translating into `"C:\Program`, `$3`=`Files\Sublime`, etc.  With this inelegant solution, it will simply put them all back together again, with the spaces and perhaps some trailing spaces that we don't care about after the last double quote.

You could experiment with escaping each space via the carrot symbol, e.g., `C:\Program^ Files\Sublime^ Text^ 3\Data\Packages`, but I don't think that it will work and you don't want to remember to put a carrot symbol every time.

If you can remove the spaces from your OneDrive path (spaces are evil, especially in the Microsoft cmd prompt), you could solve this much more elegantly via:

```powershell
alias cloud2=mklink /J C:\temp\OneDrive_chjensen\$*
```

The `$*` means everything after the `cloud` command.

**Given what I've said above, what I would actually suggest...**
if at all possible, transition to using the PowerShell console in Cmder.  It will be so much simpler than using the doskey based alias'.  I wrote about a method that I use to pull in `.ps1` files to the PowerShell consoles in this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46598150/574588).

I've created an example of some PowerShell that you could use (depending on your PowerShell version) to do the same thing, but with a lot more error checking and flexibility. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/feedback_symbolic) for more on PowerShell symbolic links.

Additionally, consider using `$env:USERPROFILE` instead of `C:\Users\chjensen` to make the script more reusable on other machines (also, `$env:ProgramFiles` instead of `c:\Program Files`).

```powershell
function Get-DestPath
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( [AllowNull()][String] $DestPath )

    if (!$DestPath)
    {
        # set to default
        $DestPath = 'C:\temp\OneDrive - chjensen\'
    }

    return $DestPath
}

function New-SymbolicLinkItem
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $NewLinkName 
        ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $ItemToLink
        ,[AllowNull()][String] $DestPath
    )

    $DestPath = Get-DestPath -DestPath $DestPath

    Write-Verbose -Message ('New Link: NewLinkName={0}, ItemToLink={1}, DestPath={2}' -f $NewLinkName, $ItemToLink, $DestPath)

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ItemToLink, 'New-SymbolicLinkItem'))
    {
        try
        {
            New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path $DestPath -Name $NewLinkName -Value $ItemToLink -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch
        {
            ('Error creating link: {0}, line number: {1}' -f $_, $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber)
        }
    }
}
Set-Alias -Name cloud -Value New-SymbolicLinkItem
```

You would use this command the same way in a PowerShell console as with the alias via:

```powershell
cloud sublime "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages"
```

I hope that this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.