# Open .sln file from cmder?

Tags: cmder

Is it possible to launch devenv.exe and open a .sln file from cmder? After I clone a git repo from the command line, I'd like to quickly open the solution in Visual Studio without having to leave cmder.

Comment: In windows cmd.exe or powershell, you can simply type xxx.sln in the command line and open it (if your visual studio is correctly installed, which means .sln file types are correctly associated with VS, you can check APPS->Default APPS in the settings in win10). Since cmder wraps cmd/ps, it should work in the same way.

Comment: You're completely right. Thanks, Danny!

Comment: Install [WhatsNew](https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/whats-new#open-visual-studio-solutions-from-the-command-line). Navigate to repository in cmdler. Type `sln`. Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Danny is correct, you simply type `xxx.sln`.

I'm a bit lazy and developed the script below to be able to type `vs` and it will find and open the first sln file it finds in the current directory.

Here are some example commands:

1. `vs` - Will open the first sln file it finds, if it doesn't find one it will just open Visual Studio without a solution. I default to opening with Visual Studio 2017.  Just change the `default` case in the `Get-VisualStudioCommand` function if you'd rather default to a different version.
2. `vs 15` - I have a bunch of versions of Visual Studio on my machine, so this will open similarly to `vs`, but will open with Visual Studio 2015.
3. `vs 13 'helloWorld.sln'` - this will open a specific sln file, i.e., `helloWorld.sln`.  One of the projects I worked on recently had multiple solutions in the same directory.
4. `vs -WhatIf -Verbose` - this will show you what the script would do if it ran and will print out the Write-Verbose messages.  Handy for debugging.  I show and example of this in the image below.

For this solution, I'm assuming that you're using a PowerShell console.  If so, you can define a `.ps1` file that will run before the console opens via the `-File` option.  It's like defining a different PowerShell profile with different commands per console window (very powerful).

See the image below where I show going to settings and modify the `PowerShell:PowerShell` task to execute `PowerShell -NoExit -NoLogo -File C:\src\ps\Cmder\general_setup.ps1 -new_console:d:"C:\src"`

Here is the image (note, although I use an alias for `ls` that outputs in PowerShell like a Linux `ls` command...this is a PowerShell console):
[image: cmder setup]

If you add the following script to the `C:\src\ps\Cmder\general_setup.ps1` file (or wherever you want to put it)...you can then type in `vs` and it will execute.  Notice in the `Get-VisualStudioCommand` function, I've put all the file paths...not the most elegant looking code, but if your file paths to `devenv.exe` are different than mine, just change them there.

Note, you could also get fancy and add a pass-through to the `-ArgumentList` or flag for the `/SafeMode` command to be able to open Visual Studio in safe mode when needed, I've just created these as a quick and dirty shortcut.

```powershell
function Get-VisualStudioCommand
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( [AllowNull()][String] $vsVersion )
    $vs10 = """${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"""
    $vs13 = """${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"""
    $vs15 = """${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"""
    $vs17 = """${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"""

    switch ($vsVersion) 
    { 
        '10' {$vs10}
        '13' {$vs13}
        '15' {$vs15} 
        '17' {$vs17} 
        default {$vs17} 
    }
}

function Get-SolutionName
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ( [AllowNull()][String] $Name )

    if (!$Name)
    {
        $Name = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.sln
    }

    if ($Name)
    {
        $Name = ('"{0}"' -f $Name)
    }

    return $Name
}

function Start-VisualStudioProcess
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param([String]$Version, [String]$Sln)

    $VsCommand = Get-VisualStudioCommand -vsVersion $Version
    $Sln = Get-SolutionName -Name $Sln

    Write-Verbose -Message ('Starting: command={0} solutionName={1}' -f $VsCommand, $Sln)

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($VsCommand, 'Start-Process'))
    {
        if ($Sln)
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath $vsCommand -ArgumentList $sln
        }
        else
        {
            Start-Process -FilePath $vsCommand 
        }

    }
}
Set-Alias -Name vs -Value Start-VisualStudioProcess
```

Let me know if you have any questions.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your prompt(cmd, cmder, etc.)

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey vs=for /f \"delims=\" %a IN ('dir /b *.sln') do start %a" /f
```

Write "vs" for open the first *.sln in folder of Solution and be happy!